# How shall one deal with renv::restore() error in R language?

Tags: r

I run renv::restore() and got the following error. What shall one do?

```
> renv::restore()
The following package(s) will be updated:

# CRAN ===============================
- MASS            [7.3-57 -> 7.3-53]
...
- zoo             [* -> 1.8-8]

# GitHub =============================
- renv            [rstudio/renv@HEAD: b27db509 -> 1f83e36b]

Do you want to proceed? [y/N]: y
Retrieving 'http://cran.stat.sfu.ca/src/contrib/Archive/boot/boot_1.3-25.tar.gz' ...
    OK [file is up to date]
Error: failed to retrieve package 'boot'
```

Comment: Looks like it can't access the site where the package is hosted. Can you try using another cran mirror?

Comment: I ended up with a branch that does not use renv.